# Getting position of the div by jquery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I did this before and it worked now for some reason it does not.

First I am having page with `header 100px footer 50px` and `div` between with `calc(100% - 150px)`.

Inside that div with jquery `load()` I load some new file with this content:

```
<div class="this">
    <div class="serviceP">
        <div class="imgS" style="background: url('./img/logo.png'); background-size: 100% 100%;"></div>
        <div class="descriptionS">sasa</div>
    </div>
    <div class="serviceP">
        <div class="descriptionS" id="sese">sasa</div>
        <div class="imgS" style="background: url('./img/logo.png'); background-size: 100% 100%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="serviceP" id="sasa">
        <div class="imgS" style="background: url('./img/logo.png'); background-size: 100% 100%;"></div>
        <div class="descriptionS">LALALLALALLAA</div>
    </div>
</div>

.this{
    padding-left: 160px; 
    padding-right: 160px;
    width: calc(100% - 320px);
    height: auto;
}
.serviceP{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.imgS{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.descriptionS{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var elementPos = $('#sese').offset();
    alert(elementPos.top);
    $("html body").animate({scrollTop: elementPos.top + 'px'}); 
});
```

If I use `position()` I get result `= 0;` if I use `offset()` I do not get the right positions like for `#sasa` I get `120` and for `#sese 170` but there must be at least `320px by css code` between top from those two elements...

Is it because it is loaded inside div before?

UPDATE:

It seems I have some problems with web browsers cache it does not show the latest code after few reloads or reopens even when I reinstall them..

Comment: Seems to work fine when i run your code

Comment: I just wanted to update I tried on different browser, idk why after 5-6 reloads or reopens and after reinstall my browsers cache is problem it doesn't show codes I added...